# Slicing each line from data CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a movie dataset that looks like this:

```
1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
2,Jumanji (1995),Adventure|Children|Fantasy
3,Grumpier Old Men (1995),Comedy|Romance
4,Waiting to Exhale (1995),Comedy|Drama|Romance
5,Father of the Bride Part II (1995),Comedy
6,Heat (1995),Action|Crime|Thriller
7,Sabrina (1995),Comedy|Romance
8,Tom and Huck (1995),Adventure|Children
```

I want to extract only the last part (genres part, e.g, Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy) and store them in a list list`[Adventure, Animation, Children, Comedy, Fantasy]`. However, I am still stuck at slicing step. I don't know how to do that since `line[:-1]` doesn't slice. I use Python 2.7

```
with open(path + 'movie.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line[:-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(path + 'movie.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.split(',')[:-1].rstrip('\n').split('|')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your slice will return the last character of each line, since the lines are not splitted when you read the file in regular manner. You should read the file using `csv` module that separates the lines automatically with ',' delimiter. Then split the result with `|`.

```
import csv
with open(path + 'movie.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(row[-1].split('|'))
```